# Quickbooks Add-On Service Discontinued on 5/31

Tags: online-banking, quickbooks

I am using QuickBooks Pro 2016.  I received a notice that Online banking will stop working after 5/31.  My question is if automatic bank transaction sync going to stop working only and/or the ability to import QBO files will stop working too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably get a reliable answer more quickly through QuickBooks support.

Comment: They told me Quickbooks will stop importing QBO files downloaded from the bank but I have a suspicion that they are trying to sell me a new version of Quickbooks or they did not understand my question because the QBO standard has been around for sometime and without changes to the standard, I do not see why it would stop working.  I am wondering if anybody has tested this?